# iOS Detect tap down and touch up of a UIView

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am stuck with a problem of determining how to detect a UIView being touched down and UIView being tapped. When it is touched down, I want the UIView to change its background color. When it is touched, I would like the UIView to perform certain tasks. I would like to know how I am able to fix this problem.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{        
    UITapGestureRecognizer *dismissGestureRecognition = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDismissDoubleTap:)];
    dismissGestureRecognition.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [sectionDismissDoubleView addGestureRecognizer:dismissGestureRecognition];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *dismissGestureDownRecognition = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissGestureDownRecognition:)];
    dismissGestureRecognition.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [sectionDismissDoubleView addGestureRecognizer:dismissGestureDownRecognition];
}

- (void)handleDismissDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)tap {
    SettingsDismissDoubleViewController *settingsDouble = [[SettingsDismissDoubleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsDismissDoubleViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsDouble animated:YES];
}

- (void)dismissGestureDownRecognition:(UIGestureRecognizer*)tap {
    NSLog(@"Down");
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A Gesture Recognizer is probably overkill for what you want. You probably just want to use a combination of `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `-touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

This is flawed, but it should give you and idea of what you want to do.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.touchDown = YES;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Triggered when touch is released
    if (self.isTouchDown) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.touchDown = NO;
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Triggered if touch leaves view
    if (self.isTouchDown) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.touchDown = NO;
    }
}
```

This code should go in a custom subclass of `UIView` that you create. Then use this custom view type instead of `UIView` and you'll get touch handling.

Comment: Subclassing UIView to implement this is a great way to keep the parent view scrollable.

Answer (score 64):

[image]

This method does not require subclassing anything. You just add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the view and set the `minimumPressDuration` to zero. Then you check the state when the gesture events are called to see if the touch event is beginning or ending.

Here is the entire project code for the example image above.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler))
        tap.minimumPressDuration = 0
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func tapHandler(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // there are seven possible events which must be handled

        if gesture.state == .began {
            myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            return
        }

        if gesture.state == .changed {
            print("very likely, just that the finger wiggled around while the user was holding down the button. generally, just ignore this")
            return
        }

        if gesture.state == .possible || gesture.state == .recognized {
            print("in almost all cases, simply ignore these two, unless you are creating very unusual custom subclasses")
            return
        }

        // the three remaining states are
        // .cancelled, .failed, and .ended
        // in all three cases, must return to the normal button look:
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
}
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131464/3681880) for the idea.

Comment: This will prevent a parent scrollview from scrolling

Comment: by far the best answer (as usual for Suragch!)

Comment: Genius! Just what I needed.

Comment: So basically you use longpress recogniser instead of normal tap recogniser to avoid accidentally scrolling?

Comment: @eonist try it out, TapRecognizer will only fire once you release the touch. Neither moving around nor the "touchdown" are recognized

Comment: Its awesome! Maybe add commentary about how it works. :)

Comment: Much hax, but works for my custom keyboard, thanks!

Comment: guys just be aware you have to handle **.cancelled** and **.failed** as well !

Comment: @Fattie, Good point. Would you mind editing that into my answer? I'm not really maintaining my Android and iOS answers much anymore.

Comment: @Fattie, haha, yes, I guess I did. A couple days ago I just made my first Flutter web app. And I've never seriously studied web development. It's all one code base with Flutter. Thanks for the answer edit. There were a couple variable names that were off so I updated those.

Comment: @Suragch - heh good one. yes "cross platform" is, in the abstract, an amazing concept.  (Indeed, I use Unity for most games.)  I do think that (based on only a very quick look at eg. Flutter) for some "very ux unusual/intensive" iOS apps, plain old native remains the way to go.  (But then in a business sense, I am not convinced anyone should ever do an app that is "very ux unusual/intensive"  :O )

Answer (score 6):

In every UIControl subclass (UIButton, etc) you can use this to subscribe to a specific set of UIControlEvent:

```
addTarget:action:forControlEvents
```

You should add target with appropriate selector for UIControlEventTouchDown and another target/selector for UIControlEventTouchUpInside event.

[UIControl reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents)

Comment: question is about uiview not uicontrol

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Holly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19612446/1121497) I built a `ButtonView` convenience class.

Edit: As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31829331/1121497) says, `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` reacts quite faster so I updated my class.

Usage:

```
let btn = ButtonView()
btn.onNormal = { btn.backgroundColor = .clearColor() }
btn.onPressed = { btn.backgroundColor = .blueColor() }
btn.onReleased = yourAction // Function to be called
```

Class:

```
/** View that can be pressed like a button */

import UIKit

class ButtonView : UIView {

    /* Called when the view goes to normal state (set desired appearance) */
    var onNormal = {}
    /* Called when the view goes to pressed state (set desired appearance) */
    var onPressed = {}
    /* Called when the view is released (perform desired action) */
    var onReleased = {}

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("touched:"))
        recognizer.delegate = self
        recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.0
        addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        userInteractionEnabled = true

        onNormal()
    }

    func touched(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if sender.state == .Began {
            onPressed(self)
        } else if sender.state == .Ended {
            onNormal(self)
            onReleased()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've finally changed to a version using `UIControl`, that doesn't react so quickly but has other advantages: you can drag a `UIScrollView` below if you drag over the button. This way the scroll view doesn't get stuck when you try to drag it and your drag gesture starts from where the button is.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/40740616/1121497

Answer (score 1):

First off, by your selector `handleDismissDoubleTap:`, I'd assume you're looking for a double tap to dismiss. To achieve this, you should be doing: `dismissGestureRecognition.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;`

Secondly, if by touch down you mean a prolonged tap (or a "tap and hold") kind of gesture, you should use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` instead of the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.