# Recognize when the user touches down on UICollectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

In the Facebook app they have a collection View at the top for stories. When a user taps on a cell there is a slight depression and then back, this begins happening before the user even lifts his finger off the cell.

**How could I achieve this effect? For the sake of simplicity I would like to know how to highlight that cell.**

### Update:

Something I realized is that currently when a user taps down on a cell the text labels in it disappear, how can I know where this is happening so I can animate other things?

### update 2:

I was able to get close with the following:

```
@objc private func cellLongPressHandler(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    print("TOUCH DOWN")
    // handle touch down and touch up events separately

    if sender.state == .began {


    } else if  sender.state == .ended {

    }

}
```

And then:

```
  cell.addGestureRecognizer(cellLongPressGesture) //new jun 16
```

The issue however is that when this is added, the collection View is made un-swipable and thus unusable. **How can I fix this?**

Comment: You want to detect a touchDown. Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611601/ios-detect-tap-down-and-touch-up-of-a-uiview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these methods: 
**SWIFT 4**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```